# Translation example not working anymore in Node-Red and Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, machine-translation, node-red, ibm-watson

Node-Red on bluemix provides a Watson Machine Translation node. Bluemix recently changed the translation APIs that this uses, releasing a new Watson Language Translation API. (see https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/language-translation/migrating.shtml for details)

I think this is the reason I used to get an error message in Node-Red saying that the Machine translation could not be binded.

Could you please help?

Comment: Can you provide more information, code, error messages, anything really? In its current form your question is not intelligible. Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For general support issues, you should use the node-red mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>We're currently working on updates to support the API changes in the nodes. Hopefully, we'll have this working by the end of the week.</s>

This issue has now been resolved. Please update your source and try again...